# how to load new content in linear layout android using fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, loadview

As we load Webview in fragment like this:

```
private WebView viewer = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewer = (WebView) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.tut_view, container, false);
        return viewer;
    }

    public void updateUrl(String newUrl) {
        if (viewer != null) {
            viewer.loadUrl(newUrl);
        }
    }
```

But i wanted to use linear layout instead of webview.
I try this but errors come out.

```
 private LinearLayout viewer ;
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         viewer =  (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tut_view, container, false);


        View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tut_view, null);
        return viewer;
    }
    public void updateUrl(String newUrl) {
        if (viewer != null) {


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have LinearLayout as root in your xml file. Also you do not need to cast the inflated view as return type is View. Please read the [fragment spec](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: but each time i want to reload activity in fragment view just let me know what  is the basic check in this code: 
if (viewer != null) {


    }